# Google Map showing only in Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

i have a facebook app using Heroku and i use a google map for it. The google map is displayed only in Firefox Browser. Chrome an IE will not display it!

I can't understand why and i need your help!

https://apps.facebook.com/sectorsase/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>


<script>
function initialize()
{

var IPos=new google.maps.LatLng(4.256,4.568);
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(44.438683,26.027269),
  zoom:13,
  disableDefaultUI:true,
  draggable: false, 
  zoomControl: false, 
  scrollwheel: false, 
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:IPos,
  icon:'icn.png'

  });
 var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:IPos,
  radius:3,
  strokeColor:'#0000FF',
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:'#0000FF',
  fillOpacity:0.4
  });

  myCity.setMap(map); 
  marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center><div id='googleMap' style='width:500px;height:380px;'></div></center>

</body>
</html>
```

IE ERROR:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false 
map.php
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
map.php, line 17 character 33
```

CHROME ERROR:

```
[blocked] The page at https://quiet-everglades-2697.herokuapp.com/map.php ran insecure content from http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false.  map.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined map.php:49
```

Comment: Check your Javascript console for possible errors.

Comment: i added the errors on the question check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the errors you've provided, I'm going to assume the page you're viewing is HTTPS. You're loading the Google Maps API from a non-HTTPS source. Just change the `script` tag to `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false`. Or better `//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` which will automatically fill in the http or https for you.